# Why is my scrolling textarea in java not scrolling?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have a frame f, panel Fpanel. and textarea j.

This is a part of my code.

The scroll does not seem to be working on my text area.

```
                JTextArea j=new JTextArea();
                j.setBounds(60,150, 400,400); 
                j.setMargin(new Insets(3,3,3,3));
                j.setEditable ( false ); // set textArea non-editable
                
               JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(j);
               scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  
               scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

I have added

Fpanel.add(scroll);

and

f.add(Fpanel);

to my code as well but it does not seem to be scrolling.

Am I missing a piece of the code or have I written something incorrectly?

Comment: 1) It will only scroll when you add text and the text exceeds the preferred size of the text area. 2) get rid of the setBounds() statement. You should NOT be using a null layout so that statement is not needed. Post a proper [mre] if you still have problems.

Comment: Refer to [How to Use Text Areas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) which is part of Oracle's Java tutorials.

Comment: @camickr I am convinced that it is not a good idea to gatekeep beginners out of using null layout as a strictly bad thing. It works fine as long as the window is fixed size. it also develops a "spatial feel" which is lacking for people that miss out from vb6/forms applications/vba not being a popular anymore. It's not scalable, but it's significantly simpler. We have no idea what his form looks like(it might take hours to design an equivelent with layouts). A lot of experiments are better off written as null layout than not written at all.

Comment: @Dmitry using null layout is completely wrong always, independent of the knowledge level of the developer - it never works anywhere near to fine, the slightest change in the ui will break it.  The sooner newbies learn that fact (along with using layout managers) and the fewer incorrect snippets are drifting around the better.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have a vertical scroll bar:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(panel, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

if you want to have a horizontal scroll bar:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(panel, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTOL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```